# How can I pull changes from a git repository using a project access token?

Tags: git, gitlab, access-token, git-pull

I created a project access token with sufficient rights (read_repository, write_repository, read_registry, write_registry). Now I searched for a way to pull new changes to my already created repo using that token.

I found two ways to use a project access token: 1. for pulling git registry docker images: `docker login -u <access-token-name> -p <access-token> gitlab...` and 2. for cloning repos: `git clone "https://my-project:$PROJECT_TOKEN@my.gitlab.host...`, but nothing to git pull (code, not images) with an already existing/cloned repository.

Another user but me originally cloned the repo and I don't want to use their account nor my personal account to login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use following command to pull changes with Access token:

```
git pull https://{username}:{access_token}@{RepoUrl}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab has explicit [Deploy Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/deploy_tokens/) for exactly this case. This was the only way that worked for me.

Summary from the documentation at the time of writing:

- Select **Settings > Repository**.
- Expand **Deploy tokens**.
- Select **Add token**.
- Complete the fields, and select the desired scopes.
- Select **Create deploy token**.

This creates a username of the format `gitlab+deploy-token-0815`. You can use it in the remote URL like this:

https://gitlab+deploy-token-0815:J3-9F-26g3zX-F_z15ms@gitlab.example.com/username/repo.git

Alternatively, in the section **Deploy Keys** below you can also provide SSH public keys that can then be used for deployment only.

Answer (score 0):

With an access token Gitlab creates a "bot" user - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#bot-users-for-projects

The bot's username can be found at
`"Gitlab Project page" -> "Project information" -> "Members"`

Git clone example with first project access token:

```
git clone http://project_<project-id>_bot@<project-access-token>@yourgitlab.com
```